# python ctypes point to void* error

Tags: python, ctypes

I already load dll, and when I use it, There is something wrong

and the C function is:

```
#define CV_DETECT_ENABLE_ALIGN_106 0x0000020

typedef void *cv_handle_t;

CV_SDK_API 
cv_result_t
cv_face_create_detector(
    cv_handle_t *handle,
    const char *modle_path,
    unsigned int config
);
```

In python:

```
CV_DETECT_ENABLE_ALIGN_106 = 0x00000020

cv_face_create_detector = dll.cv_face_create_detector
cv_face_create_detector.restype = c_int
cv_face_create_detector.argtypes = (POINTER(c_void_p), c_char_p, c_uint)

a = c_void_p(0)
handle_detect = byref(a)

result = cv_face_create_detector(handle_detect, None, CV_DETECT_ENABLE_ALIGN_106)
print(result)
```

The error:

```
result = cv_face_create_detector(handle_detect, None, CV_DETECT_ENABLE_ALIGN_106)

OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: The error code is the SEH code of an unhandled VC++ exception (0x6d7363 is the ASCII string "msc"), which was captured by the SEH handler in ctypes. All it tells you is that there was an unhandled exception in the underlying C++ implementation of the library. If I had to guess it would be that `modle_path` shouldn't be `NULL`; it should be the path of a "modle" file.

Comment: Also, you've misunderstood what the handle is. It should be `handle_detect = c_void_p()`. Then pass `byref(handle_detect)` for the call to store the handle value in `handle_detect`.

Comment: @eryksun thank you very much, I know the error reason, I use Spyder IDE, and run sometime, the error apear, and use powershell, the error disappearance, maybe memory limit, and thanks you remind the byref usage